# when using awswrangler to connect to Redshift, does Redshift cluster have to be publicly accessible?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I run `awswrangler.redshift.connect_temp` on a lambda in the same AWS account as the Redshift cluster. When Redshift cluster is not set to public, I get connection timeout error when running `connect_temp`:

```
[ERROR] InterfaceError: ('communication error', TimeoutError(110, 'Connection timed out'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/redshift_import_lambda.py", line 12, in handler
    with wr.redshift.connect_temp(
  File "/opt/python/awswrangler/redshift.py", line 582, in connect_temp
    return redshift_connector.connect(
  File "/opt/python/redshift_connector/__init__.py", line 365, in connect
    return Connection(
  File "/opt/python/redshift_connector/core.py", line 619, in __init__
    raise InterfaceError("communication error", e)
```

If I set cluster to be public, connection is fine.

Does Redshift cluster have to be public in order for `awswrangler` to connect?

Is there a way to set cluster to be non-public (for security reason) while making AWSWrangler connection work?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to place your lambda function in **same VPC** as your redshift cluster. This way your lambda should be able to connect to RedShift without the need for it to be public.